# Inbound Email question

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service

I am building a Visualforce page, and the idea is sales people enter some numbers, and send to their manager for approval. I got the first part done, it's send email to their manager. But we want to add a feature that, the manager can just reply to the email with the word "Approve" to approve etc. I guess the question is what reply email address should I use for the email that is sending out to the manager. Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you use an `Approval Process` for this instead? It will handle all of the email handling "approve" text parsing etc...

Comment: Well, the calculation was done front end (JavaScript). So it would be kind of hard I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using an Approval Process would be the best way to do this unless it's not possible for your use case. If not, you could write an inbound email service. [Here is a blog post](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/12/writing-an-inbound-email-service-for-salesforce-com/) with an explanation of how they work, some best practices, an example Apex class and test cases.

Answer (score 4):

You could create an inbound email service, and use that as the reply to address on the email you send to the manager.  Then, the code in the service would parse the email body for the word approve or reject and take whatever action is appropriate.